# what is the meaning of "in <module>" in File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>?

Tags: python, exception

I hope this is not a naive question. The following is the code:

```
>>> print(55/0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I understand that python has the traceback object, which is a kind of exception object I guess. My question is: what is the meaning of 
"`in <module>`" in the second line? Which module is it? Does it mean in the current module always? It does not provide any useful information, right? 
Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: write code in file and run it directly in console `python script.py` then you see your file name instead of `"<interactive input>"`. If code was imported from other file then you see this module name instead of `<module>`

Comment: Yes. I tried that and I got what you are trying to say. While that has nothing to do with the " in <module> ", right? Or I really should not worry about this nonsense.

Comment: You see `<interactive input>`,  `<module>` only when you run in Python Shell - because Shell doesn't read your code from file. Normally it shows filename and module name and it is usefull when code is in many files and modules.

Comment: I'm confused. Here is what I tried. I have a module with name import_me.py. Inside it, there is only one line of code: print(5/0). Then in my python file, I import this module and have one line of code: print("smile"). So, here is the output:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_path_to_my_python_file", line 1, in <module>
    import import_me
  File "file_path_to_my_module ", line 1, in <module>
    print(5/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Answer (score 1):

After trying the following code, I finally understand it by myself.

```
def get_age():
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    if not age.isdigit():
        my_error = TypeError("{0} is not integer".format(age))
        raise my_error
    elif age < 0:
        # Create a new instance of an exception
        my_error = ValueError("{0} is not positive".format(age))
        raise my_error
    return age

def a():

    get_age()

def b():

    a()

def c():

    b()

def d():
    try:
        c()
        print("haha")
    except ValueError:
        print("no one has negative age, you fool")
    #except TypeError:
        #print("you should input an integer, dear")

d()
```

The following is the error message when I did not handle the TypeError.

```
RESTART: the_path_to_my_python_file.py 
Please enter your age: th
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 33, in <module>
    d()
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 26, in d
    c()
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 22, in c
    b()
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 18, in b
    a()
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 14, in a
    get_age()
  File "the_path_to_my_python_file.py", line 5, in get_age
    raise my_error
TypeError: th is not integer
```

You see that it does not tell you "in module" anymore. Each time it tells you the name of the function in which the error occurs. I think that is the kind of information "in module" would provide.